# Python: Search database using SQL

Tags: python

I am new to programming and working on a homework assignment. I am trying to search a database by comparing a user's search term with any matching values from a selected column. If a user searches "Smith" and clicks on the "Smith" radio button in my GUI, all the records containing "Smith" as its author should appear. I am able to print all the records in the database, but not the records that relate to my search.

```
db = None
colNum = None

def search_db(self):
    global db
    global colNum

    self.searchTerm = self.searchvalue.get()
    dbname = 'books.db'
    if os.path.exists(dbname):
        db = sqlite3.connect(dbname)
        cursor = db.cursor()
        sql = 'SELECT * FROM BOOKS'
        cursor.execute(sql)
        rows = cursor.fetchall()
        for record in rows:
            sql_search = 'SELECT * FROM BOOKS WHERE' + ' ' + record[colNum] + ' ' + 'LIKE "%' + ' ' + self.searchTerm + '%"'
            cursor.execute(sql_search)
            searched_rows = cursor.fetchall()
        print(searched_rows)
```

The error I'm receiving is "sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column:"

Comment: This isn't your problem, but [you shouldn't build SQL statements with dynamic data in them this way](https://xkcd.com/327/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't enough information in your question to be sure, but this certainly is fishy:

```
sql_search = 'SELECT * FROM BOOKS WHERE' + ' ' + record[colNum] + ' ' + 'LIKE "%' + ' ' + self.searchTerm + '%"'
```

That `record[colNum]` is the value in a row for your column, not the name of the column. For example, if the column you wanted is `Title`, you're going to treat every title of every book as if it were a column name.

So, you end up running queries like this:

```
SELECT * FROM BOOKS WHERE The Meaning of Life: The Script like %Spam%
```

Even if that were valid SQL (quoted properly), `The Meaning of Life: The Script` is probably not a column in the `BOOKS` table.

---

Meanwhile, `SELECT *` returns the columns in an arbitrary order, so using `colNum` isn't really guaranteed to do anything useful. But, if you really want to do what you're trying to do, I think it's this:

```
sql = 'SELECT * FROM BOOKS'
cursor.execute(sql)
colName = cursor.description[colNum][0]
sql_search = 'SELECT * FROM BOOKS WHERE ' + colName + ' LIKE "%' + ' ' + self.searchTerm + '%"'
```

However, you really shouldn't be wanting to do that…

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the column name from the fields of the table, or from somewhere else. Your query uses record[colNum] but record contains rows of data. Instead, to get the field names, use something like this:

```
fields = []
for field in cursor.description:
    fields.append(field[0])
```

When you use `rows = cursor.fetchall()`, you are only getting data (and not the column headers).

Answer (score -1):

It looks to me like you are just not forming the SQL correctly. Remember that whatever you put after the LIKE clause needs to be quoted. Your SQL needs to look like

```
SELECT * FROM BOOKS WHERE Title like '%Spam%'
```

So you need another set of single quotes in there so that's why I would use double quotes to surround your Python string:

```
sql_search = "SELECT * FROM BOOKS WHERE " + record[colNum] + " LIKE '%" + self.searchTerm + "%'"
```

Comment: Not quoting correctly is often the cause of errors for these queries, but in this case it's not the cause. The record[colNum] returns a data field and not a column name.

Comment: I didn't quote record[colNum] I added the quotes to the LIKE clause. The original code had single quotes around the Python string and double quotes around the SQL string. SQL never uses double quotes to surround string constants, that's why I reversed it. When you double quote something in SQL it treats it as an identifier for a named object not as a string constant.

Comment: record[colNum] is data, not header.

Comment: normally in a LIKE clause you have col LIKE '%pattern%' so I don't understand what you mean by record[colNum] is data? The value that is in record[colNum] should be the name of a field in the SQL table. You get the message  "sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column:" because it cannot find a column named whatever value you have in there. If that is not a column name it makes no sense to do a LIKE operation on it in the first place, so I am not sure what you are trying to compare.